# What is the use of pm2 scale option?

Tags: node.js, pm2

Actually I'm unable to understand the use of `pm2 scale [app-name] 10` but I know `pm2 start app.js -i 4` is used for starting instances of app in cluster mode.

And one other question what would happen if I'll set number of clusters as **-1** means

`pm2 start app.js -i -1`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

PM2 is able to create new processes or delete currently running ones depending on the number you provide for the `scale` option, `pm2 scale N`, from the documentation: `N is a consistent number which the cluster will scale up or down`.

`pm2 scale app +3` - Adds 3 new processes to the current ones running.

`pm2 scale app 3` - Sets the number of instances to 3. thanks @Jolly for the correction.

Regarding the `-1` in `pm2 start app.js -i -1`, it means that PM2 will create a number of new processes that is equal to `(Number of Cores)-1`.

Comment: Thanks for your great answer by the can i use **pm2 scale app +3** in my server it has 2 gb ram and dual core processor

Comment: Actually pm2 scale [app] 3 will set the number of instances of [app] TO 3.

Comment: Correct, thanks for the comment, in the example above, whether it is more than 3 or less, `pm2 scale [app] [number]` will either kill the extra processes, or spin up new ones to match the number,